# multiple view modals in one view modal knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

> I have home page with two modals for login & signup. I made three js,
> for home, login and signup. I included login & signup in home but it
> gives me error in console saying following :
>
> "Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "value: function
> (){return emailOrmob }" Message: emailOrmob is not defined",
>
> Whereas, emailOrmob is defined correctly in LoginViewModal.
> Also when i type following in console

```
homeVM.loginVM.emailOrmob();
```

> it gives undefined
>
> I use this code in home js :

```
var self = this;

self.loginVM = new LoginViewModal();
self.signupVM = new SignupViewModal();
```

Comment: Hi, this is a suggestion for making your question and answer more useful for other stackoverflow members, feel free to ignore it:
1. Your answer states that the problem was with the 'data-bind' attribute, but that is not evident from your question since you haven't shown us that part of the code. So modify the question to include that part of the problem.
2. Accept your answer once you're able to, so that others know immediately that this question is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I had to change "data-bind" attribute as follows : value="homeVM.loginVM.emailOrmob"